# How to break vwait and start another vwait in same proc

Tags: tcl

To demonstrate my problem i have written a sample code like below

```
button .a -text check -command abc 
pack .a 
set a 0 
proc abc {} {
    pqr
}

proc pqr {} {
    global a
    puts "in pqr proc"
    # Want to break initial vwait
    set a 1
    # Want to start  a new vwait
    vwait a
    puts "vwait in pqr break"
}

vwait a
puts "Initial vwait break"
```

It seems by this way my initial vwait never break.

Any idea how to achieve this.
I want to break initial vwait and start a new vwait in same proc.

Answer (score 0):

The code works, but not quite as you expect. In particular, the top-level `vwait a` doesn't continue until the event processing to do with the pressing of the button finishes, which happens after the inner `vwait a` terminates. (But the outer `vwait` *is* marked to terminate; it just wants to clear its inner stack of calls first.) This is both simple, and yet very hard to work around, and it also applies to the `update` command. It's not for nothing that `update` is sometimes said in the Tcl community to be [Considered Harmful](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1255) (and yes, that also applies to `vwait`).

What you really want to do is construct your code so that it uses callbacks and only ever at most one `vwait`.

```
proc oneShotTrace {varname callbackScript} {
    upvar \#0 $varname v
    trace add variable v write [list oneShotTraceCallback $varname $callbackScript]
}
proc oneShotTraceCallback {varname callbackScript} {
    upvar \#0 $varname v
    trace remove variable v write [list oneShotTraceCallback $varname $callbackScript]
    uplevel \#0 $callbackScript
}

button .a -text check -command abc 
pack .a 
set a 0 
proc abc {} {
    pqr
}

proc pqr {} {
    global a
    puts "in pqr proc"
    # Want to break initial vwait
    set a 1
    oneShotTrace a {
        puts "vwait in pqr break"
    }
}

oneShotTrace a {
    puts "Initial vwait break"
}
vwait forever
```

This is a substantial rearrangement of your code. You can make things much less messy by using Tcl 8.6's coroutines.

```
proc oneShotTrace {varname callbackScript} {
    upvar \#0 $varname v
    trace add variable v write [list oneShotTraceCallback $varname $callbackScript]
}
proc oneShotTraceCallback {varname callbackScript} {
    upvar \#0 $varname v
    trace remove variable v write [list oneShotTraceCallback $varname $callbackScript]
    uplevel \#0 $callbackScript
}

button .a -text check -command abc 
pack .a 
set a 0 
proc abc {} {
    coroutine c[incr ::co_count] pqr
}

proc pqr {} {
    global a
    puts "in pqr proc"
    # Want to break initial vwait
    set a 1
    oneShotTrace a [info coroutine]
    yield
    puts "vwait in pqr break"
}

oneShotTrace a {
    puts "Initial vwait break"
}
vwait forever
```

Hmm, this still seems confusing. It's less bad in real code, where the complexity of keeping around a coroutine is more than justified by little things like the ease of having variables in the local stack frame stick around and a comprehensible flow. (Plus you can hide the `yield` in a procedure called inside a coroutine…)

Comment: Thanks Donal. Actual problem i was facing in my code after many click on button check there are multiple entries of proc pqr in stack. After some time it shows error like too many nested evaluations (infinite loop?)

Comment: @SaurabhS Yep, that's the problem in a nutshell. Don't call `vwait` inside a callback.